# Elegantly iterate over a CoreData relationship in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4

I've got a `ServiceGroup` entity with a one-to-many relationship to `ServiceItem` called `items`. I want to iterate over the `items` but swift seems completely ignorant of the variable type because `items` is just defined as an `NSOrderedSet?`.

The only way I've found to be able to iterate over my items is that I have to cast them using the new case syntax added to for loops recently, but this seems ridiculous since the code -should- know what the type is already.

Anyone have suggestions so that I don't have to constantly case/coerce my relationship entities?

```
if let items = self.items {
    for case let item as ServiceItem in items {
        mins += item.calculateTotalMinutes()
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you should redefine `items` to include the type of the items: `NSOrderedSet<ServiceItem>`?

Answer (score 2):

Something slightly more elegant (in my opinion) would be to use higher order functions like so:

```
let minutes = items
        .map({$0 as? ServiceItem})
        .flatMap({$0})
        .reduce(0) { (result, serviceItem) -> Double in
            return result + serviceItem.calculateTotalMinutes()
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you think that is readable and/or elegant, then I don't think you understand what words mean.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOrderedSet` has a property `array` to get the backing array. As the property returns `[Any]` you have to cast the type. And for convenience you could use `forEach`

```
if let items = self.items {
    (items.array as! [ServiceItem]).forEach {
        mins += $0.calculateTotalMinutes()
    }
}
```

or `reduce`

```
if let items = self.items {
    mins = (items.array as! [ServiceItem]).reduce(mins, { $0 + $1.calculateTotalMinutes() })
}
```